# Prolog: is there any way to generate the following items from a list?

Tags: list, prolog

I want to develop a predicate in prolog called next, which given a list returns another list with the N elements following the last value of the list where N is the size of the main list. For example: `next([1,2,3,4], R).`
will return `R = [5,6,7,8].` or: `next([11,12,13], R).` It will return `R = [14,15,16].`

The problem I have is that if I iterate over the main list until I am left with its last element and start adding the next one to it to the result list, I don't know how many times I should iterate since I don't know what the length of the main list was.This is why my algorithm goes into a loop.

```
next([], []).
next([X], [X1|Res]) :-  X1 is X + 1, next3([X1],Res),!.
next([H|T], [X]) :- next3(T, X).
```

Comment: Can you define an auxiliary predicate `nextN(X, N, R)` which unifies `R` with the `N` elements after `X`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

Here we use Constraint Logic Programming to constraint the elements of the result list to be increasing-monotonically-by-1 but just set them to actual values (in one instruction) once we know the last element of the input list.

We also use an open list (a list with an unbound fin) instead of append/3 to grow the output list at its end efficiently. This idiom called "using a difference list".

Finally we add test cases.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

% ---
% Called by the customer
% ---

nextor([],[]) :- !.                             % Empty input list means no work to do!

nextor([X|Xs],Out) :-                           % The input list contains at least 1 element
   assertion(integer(X)),                       % This is for stating what we assume
   OpenList = [K|Fin],                          % We will create a list of fresh variables; in order
                                                % _to append easily, the list is kept "open", i.e. its tail end
                                                % _is not [] as in a proper list but an unbound variable
                                                % _(namely, Fin). The first element is as yet undefined,
                                                % it is the fresh variable K.
   assertion(\+is_list(OpenList)),              % Not a list at present time.
   nextor_w(X,Xs,[K|Fin],LastFin,LastX),        % Processing the list with the first element X already
                                                % _separated out (for assertions). To grow the OpenList at
                                                % _its end, we just need Fin (we don't care about that list's
                                                % Tip when we grow it at the end). Finally, to communicate
                                                % the last Fin set up in the depth of the recursion to this 
                                                % call place, use LastFin. The last X found will be in LastX.
   LastFin=[],                                  % The open list is close (made proper list) by setting its
                                                % _final Fin to [].
   assertion(is_list(OpenList)),                % Yes, it is a list now!
   K #= LastX+1,                                % Now that LastX is known, we know K too.
                                                % _The constraint propagates down the list, fixing the still
                                                % unbound variables in OpenList (which is now a closed list).                                             
   Out = OpenList.                              % Unify for result.

% ---
% Does the recursion down the input list
% ---

nextor_w(Xp,[],[_|Fin],Fin,Xp) :- !.            % At the end of recursion, communicate the "last X" and the 
                                                % and the "latest Fin" back to the caller.

nextor_w(Xp,[X|Xs],[K|Fin],FinOut,XpOut) :-
  assertion(Xp+1 =:= X),                        % The input list is assumed to increase monotonously.
  Kn #= K+1,                                    % Next K is constrained to be previous K + 1,
  Fin = [Kn|NewFin],                            % The Fin of the open list is set to a new list cell, with a new Fin
  nextor_w(X,Xs,[Kn|NewFin],FinOut,XpOut).

% ---
% Testing
% ---

:- begin_tests(nextor).

test("empty list" ,true(R == [])) :-
   nextor([],R).

test("1-elem list",true(R == [2])) :-
   nextor([1],R).

test("2-elem list",true(R == [3,4])) :-
   nextor([1,2],R).

test("3-elem list",true(R == [4,5,6])) :-
   nextor([1,2,3],R).

:- end_tests(nextor).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: nextor .... done
% All 4 tests passed
```

true.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing:

```
next(In,Out) :-
    length(In,N), 
    maplist(plus(N),In,Out).
```

Uses [length/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=length/2) and [maplist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/3). This works for the examples in your question - `next([1,2,3,4],R).` and `next([11,12,13],R).` - but only because the lists contain consecutive numbers. `next([23,2,18],R).` will unify `R` with `[26,5,21]`.

Or:

```
next(In,Out) :-
    length(In,N), 
    last(In,LastValue),
    MinValue is LastValue+1,
    MaxValue is LastValue+N,
    numlist(MinValue,MaxValue,Out).
```

Uses [last/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=last/2) and [numlist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=numlist/3). With this approach `next([23,2,18],R).` will unify `R` with `[19,20,21]`.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
next(Xs,Ys) :-
    next(Xs,[_],Ys).

next([_],[],[]).
next([X],[_|Q],[X1|R]) :-
    X1 is X + 1,
    next([X1],Q,R).
next([_|T],Q,R) :-
    next(T,[_|Q],R).
```

As it runs down the list it is building up a second list. When it finds the end of the first list it then runs down the second list building the output.

I got this kind of output:

```
?- next([1,2,3,7,8],W).
W = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13] .
```